# Tag Cloud - Total Results

Tags: solspace-tag

I have the below code to display the tags that are returned inside of low_search:results.

```
{exp:low_search:results query="{segment_3}" limit="100" orderby="title" sort="asc" status="not closed" disable="category_fields|member_data" paginate="bottom" collection="library"}

    <!-- Keywords -->
    {if low_search_keywords}
        Keyword searched for <strong>{low_search_keywords}</strong>.
        <br>
    {/if}
    <!-- Categories -->
    {if low_search_category}
        {exp:channel:categories show="{low_search_category}" style="linear"}
          Type searched for: <strong>{category_name}</strong>.
        {/exp:channel:categories}
        <br>
    {/if}
    <!-- Tags -->
    {if low_search_tag_id}
        Tag searched for:
        {exp:tag:cloud tag_id="{low_search_tag_id}"}
             <strong>{tag}</strong>{if count != total_results},&nbsp;{/if}
        {/exp:tag:cloud}
        <br>
    {/if}
    <!-- Total -->
    Total results: <strong>{absolute_results}</strong>.

{/exp:low_search:results}
```

But instead of returning the total number of tags, the total_results variable is returning the total number of search results.

Is there any way to remedy this? Thank you.

Comment: Is this the only code on the template? Sounds like this is only half the story and there's an outer tag pair (and/or other tags involved) wrapped around `{exp:tag:cloud}` perhaps parsing {total_results} before `{exp:tag:cloud}` does.

Comment: You are correct. I added more code to help with my question. Thanks.

Comment: Does Low Search use a `{total_results}` variable as well?

Comment: Yes, it appears so [Low Search](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/tags#results-tag).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

total_results always belongs to the outer most tag in nested situations. It is a common variable and this is also true for count and possibly some others I can't remember. Try playing around with using an embed to get around this problem.

```
{if low_search_tag_id}
  {embed="embeddedtemplate" passedid="{low_search_tag_id}"}
{/if}
```

Even with that there may be parse issues I am not sure sometimes using parse="inward" can help there. Without having these plugins to play around with I can't give exact answer but this should put you on the right path.

Comment: Embedding a template exactly as you suggested did the trick. Thanks.